# Mutual information of the joint distribution and the marginal distribution if two random variables are independent?

Tags: mutual-information

if $Y \rightarrow X$ and $Y \rightarrow Z$, is it possible to find the equality/inequality between
$$
I(X,Z; Y) 
$$
and
$$
I(X;Y) + I(Z;Y)
$$

Or equivently, given $I(X,Z;Y)= I(X; Y) + I (Z; Y |X)$, what's the relationship between
$$
I(Z; Y|X)
$$
and
$$
I(Z; Y)
$$